# What is the meaning of "transparent contempt"?

Tags: meaning

I came across this phrase "transparent contempt" a couple of times, but was unable to get the meaning from the context.
I am not able to track down the source.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means an expression of contempt that is not at all concealed.

Comment: +1; Also, other phrases with similar meanings include _blatant contempt_; _overt contempt_.